# Prepare for segue not working with swift

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift

I using a tableView inside a viewController. I am trying to send data to a detailViewController. But for some reason i can't push to the detail view. I am not getting any errors. Its just not working.

Here is my code for the segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject) {

        if (segue.identifier == "test") {

            let detailViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            //println(index)

            detailViewController.fromPreviousView = index


      //
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it like this `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)` (with exclamation points)?

Comment: Yes with both ! and ?

Answer (score 3):

You registering tableView cell programatically , So it will create different cell not the one in the storyboard so there is no segue.

Solution is delete this line of code `self.tableViewOutlet.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")` and give cell identifier to the cell in story board to "cell". It will work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is a bug from the last beta (4 maybe till the beta 3) release of Xcode 6. I'm facing the same problem till I have upgraded to this new version. The "prepareForSegue" method is never called. The same code worked with the previous (beta 2) release but I didn't see anything about that in the "Known issues in Xcode 6 beta 4!" section in the release notes but there is a list of IB issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code for storyboard by right clicking MyStoryBoard->Open As->Source Code.

Search for :

```
trigger="accessoryAction"
```

If you find it , delete it.

Sometime ctrl+dragging adds this additional attribute causing issues with prepareForSegue.